# Failing to recognize the importance of compactness, connectedness, and other topological notions in Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, compactness

I'm currently taking a course in Real Analysis that uses Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin, and having a somewhat difficult time on tests.

I always read that notions like compactness, connectedness, and other things covered in Chapter 2 are super important, but I just don't recognize how they come into play in later chapters like the one on Integration or Differentiation. I think this is causing me to do poorly on tests, since I fail to see connections where I should.

Does anyone have tips for doing proofs in analysis, or just in general studying it?

Comment: Do you understand some basic proofs involving compactness and connectedness? E.g. that a continuous function on a compact set has a maximum and minimum, and that a continuous function on a connected set satisfies the intermediate value property?

Comment: I am familiar with the results, but don't necessarily recall the proofs. When we were on that chapter, I don't recall having difficulty on those proofs.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614365/how-do-you-remember-theorems

Comment: I think then that's my initial suggestion - re-read those proofs, and come up with counterexamples if the hypotheses are dropped. They are the kind of result I think you should be able to reconstruct the proof of, if you really understand what compactness and connectedness are doing; so it's probably a good place to start.

Comment: I think Munkres treats these topics in hisTopology text, in a very step by step, readable way.

Comment: The is not whether you have difficulties with the proofs, instead the issue is whether you know how to express the proofs, very quickly and concisely, in the language of compacntess and connectedness.

Comment: Thank you all, I will review these proofs and try to pick out exactly where compactness and connectedness come into play. I am beginning to think I simply do not study math effectively.

Comment: Compactness is a generalisation of closed-and-boundedness, and connectedness generalises intervals.